# Oracle: Break an hour into every minute for join at any point in that hour

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a feeling I am over complicating this.
I have items being loaded on to a shelf.
I know when that item wants to get loaded and to which shelf.
In a separate table I can see which items were on which shelf between certain intervals so for e.g.
TABLEA - WAIT TABLE

| ITEM | STATUS | SHELF | WAIT_DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITEMA | WAITING | A | 02/12/21 11:20 |
| ITEMB | WAITING | A | 02/12/21 11:30 |
| ITEMB | WAITING | B | 02/12/21 11:30 |

ITEMA going to SHELF A and ITEMB can go to either SHELF A/B.
In a separate table I can see when items were loaded

TABLEB - SHELF TABLE

| ITEM | STATUS | SHELF | LOAD_DATE | UNLOAD_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITEMC | UNLOADED | A | 02/12/21 11:15 | 02/12/21 11:25 |
| ITEMD | UNLOADED | A | 02/12/21 11:15 | 02/12/21 11:28 |
| ITEME | UNLOADED | A | 02/12/21 11:15 | 02/12/21 11:19 |
| ITEMF | UNLOADED | A | 02/12/21 11:15 | 02/12/21 11:31 |
| ITEMG | UNLOADED | B | 02/12/21 11:15 | 02/12/21 11:25 |

So I want to look at TABLEA (WAIT Table), see that data but get a count of how many items are currently on the SHELF they are waiting for from TABLEB.

| ITEM | STATUS | SHELF | WAIT_DT | SHELF_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITEMA | WAITING | A | 02/12/21 11:20 | 3 |
| ITEMB | WAITING | A | 02/12/21 11:30 | 1 |
| ITEMB | WAITING | B | 02/12/21 11:30 | 0 |

In a proc I could use a cursor..for loop and get data for each row but I am trying to do this in a query at the moment.
My initial thinking, can I join to a minutely breakdown of each hour 11:15, 11:16, 11:17 etc take a count at each point and join these to the WAIT_DT.
That would give me what I need but I'm hoping there is a much easier route I am unaware of.

Any help is appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simple subquery might solve your problem.

```
SELECT a.*,
             (SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM tableB b
                 WHERE a.shelf = b.shelf
                             AND a.WAIT_DT >= b.LOAD_DATe AND a.WAIT_DT < B.UNLOAD_DATE) SHELF_COUNT
    FROM tableA a;
```

Comment: Depending on the OP's conditions, rather than using `BETWEEN`, you might want to use `AND a.wait_dt >= b.load_date AND a.wait_dt < b.unload_date` as the shelf will be unloaded at the `unload_date`.

Comment: yes, exactly. I edited. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't see the wood for the trees - this really helped.